# Number of needed iterations in finding p'th root of a number with newton method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

I need to write a parallel code for finding p'th root of n   with newton method. I know how the serial code must be. The only method I found to get rid of the do-while loop in the code is finding a formula to calculate the number of iterations, so that I can use a for loop with predetermined number of iterations.

So, I am looking for a formula to find the number of iterations in newton method to find the root of a number.  Is there any way to do so?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How small does the error have to be? You will not get the exact result with a numerical method.

Comment: Where do you start for solving $x^p=n$ ?

Comment: Do you need multi-precision or integer root? Otherwise you have $\exp(\ln(x)/p)$ and maybe one Newton step. And for complex roots there are some fractal subleties for the convergence regions.

Comment: @user132112 How will the for loop do anything to parallelize your code?  You'd still have each loop result depending serially on the previous one.

Comment: @ErickWong Well, is there any way at all to parallelize such a code?

Comment: @far You've given no relevant details about your context.  If you are doing high-precision computation, then perhaps the individual arithmetic operations could be parallelized.  Are you just trying to parallelize multiple invocations?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not code for a fixed number of iterations. You finish the loop when the difference between two consecutive iterates is smaller that a predefined error. The difference between two successive approximations is not he exact error, but almost.